# Adding a loading image for the Android application when it's built using Dreamweaver 5.5 and phonegap.js

Tags: jquery, android, mobile, cordova

Using Dreamweaver 5.5 and phonegap.js to build a native android app, is it possible to set a loading screen while the application boots?

I've been trying to figure this out, but I can't find much documentation on it.

Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to answer my own question. Dreamweaver creates a compatible project folder for Eclipse. Thus, if you load up your Eclipse with the Android SDK and ADT installed, you can easily add a splash image to your res folder. From there you can recompile your .apk file. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the view you're loading initially, I'd suggest putting an image view that's your boot image into the view, while hiding all other elements (View.GONE) initially. Once you've done all the loading/initializing you want, you can View.VISIBLE the elements you want to show and View.GONE the loading image.

Comment: This isn't what I am looking for.  Dreamweaver builds that application for Android by adding the phonegap.js file to it.  Is there somewhere in that .js file that I can specify a pre-boot image.

Comment: I have managed to answer my own question.  Dreamweaver creates a compatible project folder for Eclipse.  Thus, if you load up your Eclipse with android sdk and adt installed, you can easily add a splash image to your res folder.  From there you can recompile your .apk file.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver does create a res folder with a splash screen PNG, but you don't need Eclipse to recompile it. Just change those PNGs and recompile with dreamweaver, because it will use the new PNGs. No need to change any settings, just PNGs.